# Not able to drag and drop an element to another element , Selenium version 3.9.1, chromedriver 2.36

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, action

Url  : http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html

Action : I am trying to drag Draggable1 to the drop box
 Let me know what's wrong, as I have tried everything that's available on every forum.
How can this be achieved?

Image

[image]

Code :

```
driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul[2]/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")));

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement sourceElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='todrag']/span[1]"));
    int sourceElementWidth = sourceElement.getLocation().getX() + sourceElement.getSize().getWidth() / 2;
    int sourceElementHeight = sourceElement.getLocation().getY() + sourceElement.getSize().getHeight() / 2;
    System.out.println(sourceElementWidth + "," + sourceElementHeight);
    WebElement destinationElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydropzone']"));
    int destinationElementWidth = destinationElement.getLocation().getX()
            + destinationElement.getSize().getWidth() / 2;
    int destinationElementHeight = destinationElement.getLocation().getY()
            + destinationElement.getSize().getHeight() / 2;

    System.out.println(destinationElementWidth + "," + destinationElementHeight);

    Action action = actions.pause(2000).moveToElement(sourceElement).moveByOffset(25, 10).click().clickAndHold()
            .pause(1000).moveToElement(destinationElement, destinationElement.getSize().getWidth() / 2,
                    destinationElement.getSize().getHeight() / 2)
            .release().pause(2000).build();


    action.perform();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code :

```
      WebElement LocatorFrom=driver.findElement(<locator of from where element need to be dragged>);      

 //Element on which need to drop.           
 WebElement LocatorTo=driver.findElement(<locator where element need to be dropped>);      

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" +"var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n" +"event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" +"event.dataTransfer = {\n" +"data: {},\n" +"setData: function (key, value) {\n" +"this.data[key] = value;\n" +"},\n" +"getData: function (key) {\n" +"return this.data[key];\n" +"}\n" +"};\n" +"return event;\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n" +"if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" +"event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" +"}\n" +"if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n" +"} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" +"element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" +"}\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n" +"var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" +"dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n" +"var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n" +"dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +"var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n" +"dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"var source = arguments[0];\n" +"var destination = arguments[1];\n" +"simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);",LocatorFrom, LocatorTo);
Thread.sleep(1500);
```